# Meaning of もっとも in the following sentences

Tags: translation, words

What does もっとも mean in the following sentences?

> 日本人はしょうゆの味が好きです。**もっとも**そうでない人もいますが。
>
> この宝くじを買うと一万ドル当たりますよ。**もっとも**運がよければの話ですが。

Answer (score 5):

The 「もっとも（～～が。）」 means 「とは言え」「そうは言うものの」「ただし」, "however" "although" "for all that," "provided that ~~" or "only ~~", and is often followed by 「～～が。」, as in the formula 「Sentence. + もっとも + Sentence + が.」

It's 2⃣接続詞 (conjunction) in [デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/219472/meaning/m0u/%E3%82%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82/):

> ［接］前の事柄を肯定しつつ、例外あるいは一部相反する内容を補足するときに用いる。とはいうものの。なるほどそうだが。ただし。「旅行にはみんな参加する。もっとも行かない人も二、三いるが」

So your sentences would translate to something like:

> - 日本人はしょうゆの味が好きです。**もっとも**そうでない人もいます**が**。
>     Japanese people are fond of the taste of soy sauce, although there also are people who aren't.
> - この宝くじを買うと一万ドル当たりますよ。**もっとも**運がよければの話です**が**。
>     Buy this lottery ticket and you'll win 10,000 dollars -- only if [provided that] you're lucky.

Some more examples*:

> - 彼は力が強い、もっとも体も大きいがね。
>     He is strong, but then he is big, too.
> - 女にはこの仕事はできない、もっとも例外はあるが。
>     Women cannot do this job, although there are some exceptions.
> - 彼はよく人と約束する。もっとも履行した例はないが。
>     He makes promises, only [though] he never keeps them.
> - 彼女は英語を話すのがへただ。もっとも、日本語で話すのもそううまくないが。
>     She speaks English very poorly. She doesn't speak Japanese so well either, though.

<sub>* Examples taken from *New Japanese-English Dictionary* (Kenkyusha) and *Progressive Japanese-English Dictionary* (Shogakukan)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

This もっとも is not 最も but 尤も (although both are cognates). You can replace it by 当然 in both of your example sentences.

Comment: @user326441 If you want more about it here is its entry: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/219472/meaning/m0u/%E3%82%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82/ (the meaning used here is labeled "black-boxed 2")

Comment: もっとも in the sense of 当然 is a na-adjective and not a conjunction, and it's used like 「～～(する)のももっともだ」, no?

Comment: I don't know I never seen it used like that (lack of exposure). When I said, you can replace it with 当然 I had the word "indeed" in my mind. 当然 (little pause) そうでない人もいますが。(Indeed, there is also people who don't)